# Safari 9.0.3 requires login for every new tab

Tags: safari, macos

Safari 9.0.3 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

### Issues

1. I launch Safari > Login to Gmail,ebay or any other site > Login Successful
2. Open New Tab and if i go to gmail or ebay or the site that i had open in the first tab, it wants me to login again, so login session seems limited to just the original tab
3. I close Safari launch same website again and it wants me to login again

Above issue is not happening in FireFox or Chrome, in those browser, my gmail session stays persistent b/w browser and even OS restarts

Comment: Two things I can think of:
1) Are you using Private Browsing? Doubtful since this should go away when you close the window.
2) Are your cookie settings set correctly? `Preferences` → `Privacy` → `Allow from websites I visit`.

Comment: 1. Not using Private Browsing 2. Already set to Allow from websites i visit

Comment: Manually Resetting Safari 9.0.3 fixed my issue http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231274/how-to-reset-safari-9-0-3