# How to reset safari 9.0.3

Tags: safari, macos

In older versions there was an option to reset safari

But in 9.0.3 I am not seeing this option

What are the alternatives?
How can I reset safari 9.0.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari can also be reset from the command line.

Open a Terminal window and type the following or to be safe launch finder and navigate to the following locations and manually delete or move these

```
mv ~/Library/Safari ~/Desktop/Safari-`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/Apple\ -\ Safari\ -\ Safari\ Extensions\ Gallery;
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.LSSharedFileList.plist; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.RSS.plist; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist;
```

This should give you a fresh Safari with the menu item option to reset Safari again.

Comment: i edited the answer with correct information and removed assumptions about 9.0.3

Comment: This just solved a particularly annoying problem for me where Google would appear signed out every time I opened a new tab.